# ERROR #98124 WEBPACK when running `gatsby develop`

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, contentful

Everything started after installing `gatsby-source-contentful: ^2.3.42 => 2.3.43`.

**ERROR #98124 WEBPACK**

Generating development JavaScript bundle failed
Can't resolve 'history' in `/Users/labanino/development/my-app/node_modules/gatsby-link`
If you're trying to use a package make sure that 'history' is installed. If you're trying to use a local file make sure that the path is correct.
File: `node_modules/gatsby-link/index.js`

**ERROR #98124 WEBPACK**

Generating development JavaScript bundle failed
Can't resolve `react-router-dom` in `/Users/labanino/development/my-app/node_modules/gatsby-link`
If you're trying to use a package make sure that `react-router-dom` is installed. If you're trying to use a local file make sure that the path is correct.
File: `node_modules/gatsby-link/index.js`
failed Building development bundle - 7.565s

This is my `gatsby info`

**System:**

```
OS: macOS 10.15.6
CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3615QM CPU @ 2.30GHz
Shell: 5.7.1 - /bin/zsh
```

**Binaries:**

```
Node: 12.16.2 - /usr/local/bin/node
npm: 6.14.4 - /usr/local/bin/npm
```

**Languages:**

```
Python: 2.7.16 - /usr/bin/python
```

**Browsers:**

```
Chrome: 85.0.4183.102
Safari: 13.1.2
```

**npmPackages:**

```
gatsby: ^2.24.55 => 2.24.55
gatsby-link: ^1.6.40 => 1.6.46
gatsby-plugin-react-helmet: ^3.3.10 => 3.3.10
gatsby-source-contentful: ^2.3.42 => 2.3.43
```

**npmGlobalPackages:**

```
gatsby-cli: 2.12.93
```

Comment: Seems like `gatsby-link` is trying to import `history`, but no such module exists. This is a situation that can probably be resolved by removing your `node_modules` folder and reinstalling dependencies, then running `gatsby clean` before re-running `gatsby develop`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update `gatsby-link`. in `packages.json` change:

```json
gatsby-link: ^1.6.40 => 1.6.46
```

to

```json
gatsby-link: ^2.4.13 => 2.4.13
```